# Replace all occurrences using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

The code below works perfectly:

```
$string = '(test1)';
$new = preg_replace('/^\(+.+\)+$/','word',$string);
echo $new;
```

Output:

```
word
```

If the code is this:

```
$string = '(test1) (test2) (test3)';
```

How to generate output:
`word word word`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why my regex do not work ?

- `^ and $` are anchors which means match should start from start of string and expand upto end of string
- `.` means match anything except newline, `+` means one or more, by default regex is greedy in nature so it tries to match as much as possible where as we want to match `( )` so we need to change the pattern a bit

You can use

```
\([^)]+\)
```

[image]

---

```
$string = '(test1) (test2) (test3)';
$new = preg_replace('/\([^)]+\)/','word',$string);
echo $new;
```

---

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/GVQxhV/1/)